# Bibliography style using first initial(s) – last name

Tags: bibtex, natbib

There is likely a very easy hack or a predefined solution somewhere on the tip of my nose that I just haven't found yet …

I'm using the `natbib` package and `achemso.bst` bibliography style for my thesis at the moment. It does 99 % of what it should. I wish I could now change the order of initials and last name. Bonus points if the page numbers are turned into starting page only from the page range that exists atm. One could call this the Wiley-VCH style because it's what *Angewandte*, *Eur. J. Org. Chem.* and others use. Alas, they discourage TeX to the point of not having a bst file anywhere easily downloaded.

Elsevier seem to follow the ACS style, while RSC publications are close to Wiley but bold the issue instead of the year – at least that's what I saw in the one recent *Chem. Commun.* article I have downloaded for my thesis so far.

This is all in the bibliography section; all references in text are subscript numerical ones in square brackets. Unless I decide to use `\citeauthors` accidentally.

Output is:

[1] Clark, W.; Still, W. C.; Kahn, M.; Mitra, A. *J. Org. Chem.* **1978**, *43*, 2923–2925.

Output should be:

[1] W. Clark, W. C. Still, M. Kahn, A. Mitra *J. Org. Chem.* **1978**, *43*, 2923–2925 (–2925 can be missing, according to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\usepackage{rsc} provides the \bibliographystyles{rsc} and {angew}. The latter is what you are looking for (except for removing the page range; this you may have to hard-edit in your .bib file)

Comment: I knew it was something absurdly simple and easy … Thanks!